# How can I dynamically toggle the allowBackup attribute from an Activity in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-manifest

How to dynamically change allowbackup to true or false from the Activity class.

I know we can change it from manifest but I want to provide my user a toggle button so he decides weather or not he wants to allow the back or not.

Answer (score 0):

`allowBackup` is an entry in the app's `AndroidManifest.xml`. This file is part of the APK and can not be changed after the app APK has ben built.

There is only the option I see would be to create two flavors, one with `allowBackup=true` and the other with `allowBackup=false`.

Note that is your app has a `targetSdk` of 31 or higher it doesn't matter if your set `allowBackup` to true or false, `adb backup` will ignore the app because [Google changed the adb backup behavior in Android 12](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12#adb-backup-restrictions). So it only affects online backup.